# Value of listing OEIS contributions on an academic CV

Tags: publications, job-search, cv, faculty-application

The [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/) is a large online database of number sequences.  It's popular among professional and amateur mathematicians, and its entries are widely cited.  Like Wikipedia, most of its content is authored and edited by the community; no particular qualifications are required to participate, though in my experience most active editors are working mathematicians or scientists.

I've occasionally seen academic CVs which list OEIS contributions among the publications (usually in a separate subsection).  I've also seen CVs of known contributors which make no mention whatsoever of their OEIS contributions.

I was wondering, then, whether listing OEIS contributions is generally a good idea when applying for academic jobs such as post-docs and professorships.  How much weight, if any, do recruiting committees in math and computer science place on OEIS contributions?  Are they viewed as minor professional publications, as non-academic community service, or as unwanted and annoying CV padding?

Related question: [Value of contributions to Wikipedia when applying for academic jobs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/value-of-contributions-to-wikipedia-when-applying-for-academic-jobs)

Answer (score 3):

Important: separate section.  So no one thinks you are trying to sneak them in as equal to publications.

Probably it will have no weight for recruiting.  I suppose having the list there may cause someone on the committee to say "I've heard of this guy."

But CVs have uses other than job searches.  So go ahead and include them if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of contribution is important and not as much credited as it should be. But I wouldn't suggest to include single contributions to OEIS or other things like that in a CV. Two reasons:

1. You are not the author and it's an impossible task to include the author list.
2. It clutters the CV and makes it unreadable long.

However, it deserves its space. In Economics, there is often a section in CVs called *Service*. It is about refereeing activities and faculty jobs. I would mention there that I contribute to OEIS or Wikipedia. Alternatively, you mention it on your personal website. Recruites look there, too.

Comment: Why do you say that those who write OEIS entries are not authors?  What else would they be?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how OEIS works, but when it's like Wikipedia, I'd say: it's hard to say when a contributor is an author. And to be honest (in a CV), the author would have to name all other authors as well.

Comment: I have already published 16 sequences on it and only in one case I was named as coauthor because one of the editors joined with me for completing the work and in all the rest I am the  author. If you define the sequence and could able to find the terms, that honour should be given to you. Am I wrong?